# My app looks different scale when i change phone

Tags: android, xml

I've created my android application. The app is complete but it's a problem: when I install this app in other smartphone, objects,that normally are in the screen, are overlapping or not in original position.
My IDE is Android Studio 2.2

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <pl.pawelkleczkowski.customgauge.CustomGauge
        android:id="@+id/gaugePH"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        app:gaugePointStartColor="@color/md_red_900"
        app:gaugePointEndColor="@color/md_red_900"
        app:gaugePointSize="5"
        app:gaugeStartAngle="135"
        app:gaugeStrokeCap="ROUND"
        app:gaugeStrokeColor="@color/md_grey_400"
        app:gaugeStrokeWidth="10dp"
        app:gaugeStartValue="0"
        app:gaugeEndValue="14"
        app:gaugeSweepAngle="270"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/gaugePressione"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

    <pl.pawelkleczkowski.customgauge.CustomGauge
        android:id="@+id/gaugePressione"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        app:gaugePointStartColor="@color/md_blue_900"
        app:gaugePointEndColor="@color/md_blue_900"
        app:gaugePointSize="5"
        app:gaugeStartAngle="135"
        app:gaugeStrokeCap="ROUND"
        app:gaugeStrokeColor="@color/md_grey_400"
        app:gaugeStrokeWidth="10dp"
        app:gaugeStartValue="0"
        app:gaugeEndValue="15"
        app:gaugeSweepAngle="270"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textPH"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0.0"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textStrPH"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textPressione"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0.0"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textStrPressione"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textStrPressione"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Bar"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textPressione"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/gaugePressione"
        android:layout_marginLeft= "70dp"
        android:textColor="@color/md_black_1000"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textStrPH"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="PH"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/gaugePH"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textStrPressione"
        android:layout_marginRight= "70dp"
        android:textColor="@color/md_black_1000"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/goMaps"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Mappa"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTemperatura"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0.0"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textUmidita"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textStrPressione"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textStrTemperatura"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="°C"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:layout_marginLeft= "70dp"
        android:textColor="@color/md_black_1000"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textPressione"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textTemperatura"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textUmidita"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0.0"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textPH"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/gaugeUmidita"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textStrUmidita"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="%"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:layout_marginLeft= "70dp"
        android:textColor="@color/md_black_1000"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textStrTemperatura"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textStrTemperatura"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textStrPH" />

    <pl.pawelkleczkowski.customgauge.CustomGauge
        android:id="@+id/gaugeUmidita"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        app:gaugePointStartColor="@color/md_red_900"
        app:gaugePointEndColor="@color/md_red_900"
        app:gaugePointSize="5"
        app:gaugeStartAngle="135"
        app:gaugeStrokeCap="ROUND"
        app:gaugeStrokeColor="@color/md_grey_400"
        app:gaugeStrokeWidth="10dp"
        app:gaugeStartValue="0"
        app:gaugeEndValue="100"
        app:gaugeSweepAngle="270"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/gaugeTemperatura"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

    <pl.pawelkleczkowski.customgauge.CustomGauge
        android:id="@+id/gaugeTemperatura"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        app:gaugePointStartColor="@color/md_blue_900"
        app:gaugePointEndColor="@color/md_blue_900"
        app:gaugePointSize="5"
        app:gaugeStartAngle="135"
        app:gaugeStrokeCap="ROUND"
        app:gaugeStrokeColor="@color/md_grey_400"
        app:gaugeStrokeWidth="10dp"
        app:gaugeStartValue="-20"
        app:gaugeEndValue="50"
        app:gaugeSweepAngle="270"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gaugePressione"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textImpianto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Impianto:"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textCodImpianto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="145dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You should always use `sp` for text size, not `dp`

Answer (score 0):

There is not a simple answer but start reading Supporting Different Screen Sizes documentation at https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are using hard coded values for height and width. Those values have dp  - which is density pixel. Since the screens are different, the pixels on those screens will also be different, so those values "will not work".

You should try to use match_parent (which will fill all the space they can within the parent) or wrap_content which will use only the needed space. Usually the width is match_parent and the height is wrap_content.

If have more than one element on that layout, you can also try to use weight, which basically will give a certain percentage to each one of the elements.
Imagine one element with android:weight="1" and  another one with android:weight="2". Both those elements will have different "percentages" of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

What are the views that are causing problems?
Are `@id/goMaps`, `@id/textCodImpianto` or `@id/textImpianto` among them?
Here is what Android Studio editor has to say about it (once I replaced hard-coded text with resources):

`@id/goMaps can overlap @id/textCodImpianto if @string/_0, @string/mappa grow due to localized text expansion less... (Ctrl+F1) 
If relative layout has text or button items aligned to left and right sides they can overlap each other due to localized text expansion unless they have mutual constraints like toEndOf/toStartOf`

Substitute text size change with screen size change (the same effect in this case) and you have at least one explanation about why some of your views are overlapping or moved.

At the very least, you are lacking some constraints.